# iterate through a dictionary to create a csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, directory, tree

I am trying to write a python 3.6 script that will add key/value pairs from a folder tree dictionary to a csv file. Files in the folder three are the keys and their paths are the values.

There seems to be an error in how I am iterating through the dictionary because in the csv file I only get the key/value pairs from one of the folders, and not the entire folder tree. I just don't see where my error is. Here is my code:

```
import os
import csv

root_dir = '.'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk (root_dir, topdown='true'):
     folder_dict = {filename:root for filename in files}
     print (folder_dict)

with open ('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
     for key in folder_dict:
         csvfile.write ('%, %s\n'% (key, folder_dict [key]))
```

I get the dictionary but in the csv file there are only the key/value pairs for one item.

Comment: You keep overwriting `folder_dict`

Answer (score 0):

Because of the line `folder_dict = {filename:root for filename in files}`, you overwrite the data on each loop, leaving the last dictionary as the only thing for the later write to the CSV.

You don't really need this interim data structure at all. Just write the CSV as you discover files to write. You weren't actually using the CSV module, so I added it to the solution.

```
import os
import csv

root_dir = '.'

with open ('test.csv', 'w') as fileobj:
    csvfile = csv.writer(fileobj)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk (root_dir, topdown='true'):
        csvfile.writerows((filename, root) for filename in files)
```